# an ideal of matrix ring which is projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, projective-module

Let $K$ be a field and
$$
A=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
0&0&g
\end{pmatrix}
:a,\dots,g\in K
\right\},
$$
then
$$
J=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&c\\
0&0&f\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
:c,f\in K
\right\}
$$
is a two-sided ideal of $A$.
I want to show that *J* is projective
as a left *A*-module.

Now let $f\colon M\to N$ be a surjective homomorphism of left *A*-modules
and $g\colon J\to N$ be a homomorphism of left *A*-modules.
Since $J=AT$, where 
$$
T=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
if I could define $h\colon J\to M$ by $h(X)=Ym$ when $X=YT\;(Y\in A)$ and
$f(m)=g(T)$, then $fh=g$. But I'm not sure if $h$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Your ideal is isomorphic (as a left module) to $Ae$ with $e=E_{1,1}$ the elementary matrix which is all zeroes except for a $1$ at the upper left corner. Set $f=1-e$, and consider the two left ideals $Ae$ and $Ef$: show $A=Af\oplus Ae$. it follows immediately that $Ae$ is projective.